# adb command to get list of offloaded apps ( apps uninstalled while keeping their data directory)

Tags: android, adb, android-source

Android gives the feature to uninstall apps while keeping their data directory (called offloading).
This is useful for apps which we use less frequently where we can offload it to claim storage but when we need to reinstall it we don't have to sign in again.

Adb command for this : adb uninstall -k <app_package_name>

AOSP code to achieve this : https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/pm/PackageManager.java;drc=master;l=8401.

I want to get list of apps offloaded, I can find AOSP code for this :
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#getInstalledApplications(int).

What is the `adb` command to achieve this?

Reason is to offload an app programatically it is not supported in older android versions so I have to use adb command, want to find corresponding adb command to get list of offloaded apps.

Comment: does "adb shell pm list packages -u" works for you?